# How to get the filename and line number of a particular JetBrains.ReSharper.Psi.IDeclaredElement?

Tags: resharper, resharper-plugins, resharper-sdk

I want to write a test framework extension for resharper.  The docs for this are here: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/Test+Framework+Support

One aspect of this is indicating if a particular piece of code is part of a test.  The piece of code is represented as a IDeclaredElement.

Is it possible to get the filename and line number of a piece of code represented by a particular IDeclaredElement?

Following up to the response below:

@Evgeny, thanks for the answer, I wonder if you can clarify one point for me.

Suppose the user has this test open in visual studio: https://github.com/fschwiet/DreamNJasmine/blob/master/NJasmine.Tests/SampleTest.cs
Suppose the user right clicks on line 48, the "player.Resume()" expression.
Will the IDeclaredElement tell me specifically they want to run at line 48?  Or is it going to give me a IDeclaredElement corresponding to the entire class, and a filename/line number range for the entire class?

I should play with this myself, but I appreciate tapping into what you already know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

The "IDeclaredElement" entity is the code symbol (class, method, variable, etc.). It could be loaded from assembly metadata, it could be declared in source code, it could come from source code implicitly.

You can use

```
var declarations = declaredElement.GetDeclarations()
```

to get all AST elements which declares it (this could return multiple declarations for partial class, for example)

Then, for any IDeclaration, you can use

```
var documentRange = declaration.GetDocumentRange()
if (documentRange.IsValid())
  Console.WriteLine ("File: {0} Line:{1}",
 DocumentManager.GetInstance(declaration.GetSolution()).GetProjectFile(documentRange.Document).Name,
documentRange.Document.GetCoordsByOffset(documentRange.TextRange.StartOffset).Line
);
```

By the way, which test framework extension are you developing?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The framework is here: https://github.com/fschwiet/DreamNJasmine/.

Comment: Evgeny I updated the question seeking more details on what would be returned.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Will the IDeclaredElement tell me specifically they want to run at
>   line 48?

Once more: IDeclaredElement has no positions in the file. Instead, it's declaration have them.
For every declaration (IDeclaration is a regular AST node) there is range in document which covers it. In my previous example, I used TextRange.StartOffset, though you can use TextRange.EndOffset.

If you need more prcise position in the file, please traverse AST tree, and check the coordinates in the document for specific expression/statement

Comment: Thanks Evgeny.  I was not minding the difference between IDeclaredElement and the objects returned by GetDeclarations() as I'm more interested in the capability overall-- whether I can get the particular element within a delegate that was clicked.  It sounds like that will be available in the AST.  I was focused on line number, but thinking about it thats sloppy as someone could put a lot of other stuff on the same line.  Anyhow, cheers